# Ember event in one view update another?

Tags: events, view, controller, ember.js

I have a small extract from my Ember app here. My page contains a number of views each containing different data each with their own controllers.

I want a search field (in index view) to go in one view which should "talk" to the stationList controller to update the content of the stationList view. This doesn't work. I get an error: TypeError: this.get(...).search is not a function

The logging outputs the name of the contoller I've asked it to use: App.StationListController

I added a second search form inside on the StationList View. This one works just fine. The logging this time outputs a dump of the StationListController object. So I am guessing that the other search form, despite my code (in SearchFormView): controllerBinding : 'App.StationListController', is not correctly setting the controller.

So I guess my question is **why not**?

How can I route the change on the form field in the one view to call a funciton on another view's controller?

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div id="searchForm">search form view search: 
        {{#view App.SearchFormView}}
            {{view App.StationSearchField}}
        {{/view}}
    </div>

    <div id="stationList">{{render stationList}}</div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="stationList">
    station list view search: {{view App.StationSearchField}}
    <ul>
        <li>List</li>
        <li>will</li>
        <li>go</li>
        <li>here</li>
    </ul>
    {{searchTerm}}
</script>
```

And

```
App = Ember.Application.create({})

App.SearchFormView = Ember.View.extend({
    init : function()
    {
        console.log("SearchFormView init", this.get('controller'))
    }
})

App.StationSearchField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    keyUp: function(event) {
        var searchTerm = this.value

        console.log("value",searchTerm,this.get('controller'))

        this.get('controller').search(searchTerm)
    }
})

App.StationListController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content     : [],
    searchTerm  : null,

    search : function(term)
    {
        this.set("searchTerm",term)
        console.log("searching",term)
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ianbale/8QbrK/14/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `controllerBinding` stuff is from the older version, I don't think that works anymore.

You can use `controllerFor` on `get('controller')` in the `StationSearchField`.

```
    this.get('controller').controllerFor('station_list').search(searchTerm)
```

But `controllerFor` is deprecated and may be removed. Depending on your application structure you use [`needs`](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/) on the controller.

Another way which I am using, is to send a custom event from the View, which the Route then sends to the corresponding controller.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    events: {
      search: function(term) {
        controller = this.controllerFor('station_list')
        controller.search(term);
      }
    }
});
```

and dispatch a search event from view like so.

```
    this.get('controller').send('search', searchTerm);
```

The advantage of this method is you dispatch the same event from multiple places and it would get handled in the same way.

Here's the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfkzQ/).

Comment: I've brought your code into my full app and it's working fine. I'm a little concerned about the fact that controllerFor is depreciated though since you're using that in the vent handler too. Any idea what the "correct" way to do this is now?

Comment: Why is it "station_list" instead of "StationList"?

Comment: `controllerFor` is deprecated only on controllers in favor the `needs`, the controllerFor on the route is ok to use, and is unlikely to be deprecated, as its the standard way to access other controllers from routes.

Comment: Contexts/routes are snake cased by convention I think. StationList would work too, ember does a lot of this kind of the conversion internally.

Comment: Ah! OK. SO safe to use controllerFor there then :-)

Comment: I thought some more on "needs" and had another go at the controller. In the end, after trying to create a FormContoller and getting nowhere I finally realised I needed to put it into the IndexController which seems to work ok. However, it's lead to another problem (one I've seen elsewhere in my app). But I think that is something for a new question...but in a nutsehll, my searchterm and content array are being updated in my controller but the view is not updating! (updated the fiddle)

Comment: Ok. This is bizzare! If I set it up with needs : ["StationList"] then the call gets routed ok, but my view does not update. If I used needs ["station_list"] then the view updates!

Comment: Yeah, I'd stick to the conventions. There's probably a lot more magic underneath. :)